# Azure Cosmos DB Input Binding - cannot pass OFFSET and LIMIT values as params?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm experiencing an issue with trying to dynamically pass the values for `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` as query params to my CosmosDB trigger.

If I hardcode the values for these two into the query, it works as expected.

However, with this code:

```
 {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "v1/query/properties",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "propertiesInquiryInput",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "databaseName": "property",
      "collectionName": "discovery",
      "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDBConnectionString",
      "direction": "in",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.country={country} OFFSET {pageNo} LIMIT {perPage}"
    },
```

I get the following failure upon execution:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.queryProperties. Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":

{"start":48,"end":55},"code":"SC2062","message":"The OFFSET count value exceeds the maximum allowed value."},
{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":62,"end":70},"code":"SC2061","message":"The LIMIT count value exceeds the maximum allowed value."}]}
```

I'm relatively new to Azure services and their patterns, so perhaps I'm missing something obvious here. I've tried sending these values as a JSON object via POST and as query params via a GET request. Nothing seems to work.

I'm also not aware of a way to view what the SQL query that IS being fired off, so as to perhaps debug it from that angle. Any guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Update:

Adding function body for clarity:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const results = context.bindings.propertiesInquiryInput;
    !results.length && context.done(null, { status: 404, body: "[]", });

    const body = JSON.stringify(results.map(data => reshapeResponse(data));

    return context.done(null, { status: 200, body });
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe the values for pageNo and perPage are getting passed in as strings - whereas int values are expected by Cosmos DB?!

Comment: I'm using this payload: 

`
{
 "country": "United Kingdom",
 "pageNo": 1,
 "perPage": 10
}
`

Could something under the hood be changing the typing?

Comment: are you even sure the values get passed into the query? I only know this is possible with query parameters coming from the HTTP query string. I don't (or didn't until now) that this is also possible with values from the http request body

Comment: As mentioned, I've tested this both as a GET with query params and as a POST with a JSON body... both produce the same issue.

Comment: Can you post the header of your function code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean specifically by that: the header when the server responds? It's just a 500: 

Date: Mon, 29 Jul 2019 13:49:40 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 0

Comment: No your actual function source code. C# or JS I assume?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. It's JS. Added to OP.

Comment: I've also tried `{offset:int}` in my path definition. 

To wit: when passing this way, or via a JSON body with a POST, inspecting `context.bindingData` shows the value to be a number. Passing as a pure query param results in a string.

Also, of note, when I receive this "value exceeded" error, the function itself never appears to fire.

Comment: Edited the title, this is not the Cosmos DB Trigger, and the `leaseCollectionName` parameter is not needed. This is an Input Binding. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns I don't see that types other than strings are supported in the automatic binding.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta thanks for your input. so is the implication that there is no solution?

Comment: As far as I can see on the Functions docs, I didn't see support for other types, I could be missing something though, but I don't see any other documentation stating otherwise

Comment: I'm also running into this, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

*In addition to the original question:*

Got the same exception message with parametrised query and `azure.cosmos=4.2.0` pypi package for python.

Case to reproduce:

```
query = f"""
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE ...
AND c.run.submittedBy = @author
OFFSET 0 LIMIT @exp_limit
"""

items = list(cdb_container.query_items(
    query=query,
    parameters=[
        {"name":"@exp_limit", "value": f"{num_of_experiments}"}, # can't pass as param due to `The LIMIT count value exceeds the maximum allowed value.`
        {"name":"@author", "value": f"{submitter}"},
    ],
    enable_cross_partition_query=True
))
```

Workaround (with formatted string for the query):

```
num_of_experiments = 10
query = f"""
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE ...
AND c.run.submittedBy = @author
OFFSET 0 LIMIT {num_of_experiments}
"""
```

Omitted not-related parameters in `WHERE` statement for example purpose. Might be helpful for someone who is struggling with a similar case.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit late but I had the same issue and in my case this error came because of the value I passed as offet was a String. After I parsed it as Int, the query just worked like expected!